# How to draw lines with mouse in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse, lines

Im currently trying to make a pragram in visual studio WPF form, that draws lines using mouse like in paint. 
Currently it is drawing the same old line and continues drawing it but i want to     draw a new line each time i press the left mouse button    . Here's the **MainWindows.xaml.cs** code and what it looks like:

```
namespace DrawingLines
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private PathFigure _pathFigure = new PathFigure();
    PathFigureCollection _pathCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
    PathSegmentCollection _segments = new PathSegmentCollection();
    private PathGeometry _pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _pathFigure.Segments = _segments;
        _pathCollection.Add(_pathFigure);
        _pathGeometry.Figures = _pathCollection;
        myPath.Data = _pathGeometry;
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            LineSegment segment = new LineSegment();
            segment.Point = e.GetPosition(this);
            _pathFigure.Segments.Add(segment);
        }

    }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _pathFigure.StartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    }

    //private void Window_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    //{

    //}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }
}
```

}

And here's the **MainWindow.xmal** code:

```
<Window x:Class="DrawingLines.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Joonistamine" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="Window_MouseRightButtonDown">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="53*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="258*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="124*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="379*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Name="myPath" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Button Content="Exit" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Click="button1_Click" BorderBrush="Red" Foreground="#FFFF1A1A" />
</Grid>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are continually adding to the PathSegment, without clearing it when you start a new line (by clicking the left mouse button). Therefore, I would try this:

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _pathFigure.Segments.Clear();
    _pathFigure.StartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
}
```

EDIT: ... and if you want it to retain the lines and they are not necessarily connected, you need a separate Path for each line, since each Path represents a single, connected shape.

To do this, you would need to modify your code in this way:

- Remove the path from your XAML
- For every left mouse click, create a new Path and add it to the grid (myGrid.Children.Add(myPath)
- Add new points from mouse moves to the currently active path

Comment: That works but how would could i draw multiple lines without deleting the last ones?

Comment: @User_T Please see my edit. If my answer was useful to you, please consider upvoting or marking it as an answer. This is how you get free help from community members. Thanks.